# What is the difference between discrete optimal transport and linear programming?

Tags: measure-theory, optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima, optimal-transport

How unique minima are guaranteed to exist in optimal transport. Why such a thing is not possible in general linear programming problems. What theorem guarantees the existence of unique minima to exist in optimal transport?

Edit: My question is regarding Kantorowich optimal transport

For a cost function $C(x,y)$ $$W[\pi]=\bigg [\sum C(x,y)\pi(x,y)\bigg]_{\text{inf}}$$
$$\sum_{y}\pi(x,y)=\rho(x)$$
$$\sum_{x}\pi(x,y)=\tilde{\rho}(y)$$

We seek for $\pi$ which minimizes the $W$

Comment: Which optimal transport problem? There are optimal transport problems without unique minima. Just think of a constant cost function.